# I want to pipe gulp.src into two separate streams

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-s3, stream, gulp

I am trying to get gulp.src to pipe into two separate stream in my foo function.

```
gulp.src('./test/**')
    .pipe( foo( options ) );
```

One of the stream will see the files from gulp.src and determine whether or not to pipe it into gulp-s3 stream.
So if first stream succeed then pipe gulp.src data again to gulp-s3 stream.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use [gulp-if](https://www.npmjs.org/package/gulp-if) where the condition is your first "stream" and gulp-s3 is your action.